# restream the rtmp stream by using ffmpeg and nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

This is my current rtmp configuration for localhost, everything works well

```
  # Transcoding (ffmpeg needed)

   application big {

       live on;

   exec /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name -vcodec flv -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/anotherapp/${name};

   }

application anotherapp {
       live on;
  }
```

This is what I am trying to achive

```
  # Transcoding (ffmpeg needed)

   application big {

       live on;

   # rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name  -> Receive this address dynamically from outside, for example the address will be rtmp://142.204.134.93/red5app/12345
   # rtmp://localhost:1935/anotherapp/${name};  -> and create new stream on my server with the same name. 
   # So this will be the result:

   exec /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -re -i  rtmp://142.204.134.93/red5app/12345 -vcodec flv -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/anotherapp/12345;

   }

application anotherapp {
       live on;
  }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please specify what is end goal of such copying from one app to another. It might be different solutions to achieve the same.